# Calculate 'Credit Score' from Experian statutory credit report?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, experian

I ordered a statutory credit report from Experian (UK) last week and it came today.

I forgot that it doesn't include a one-off *credit score* with the report.

Is it possible to calculate a credit score based on this report?

EDIT: An approximation would more than suffice, I imagine companies like Experian don't publish their score algorithms.

Comment: Use Noddle https://www.noddle.co.uk/. It is free for life and gives you a credit score and report too.

Comment: @DumbCoder Thanks for the link. Never heard of them before. It looks like they're using some kind of government open-data or something according to BBC? Is it legit? Have you used them? I may be cyclical... but I'm very suspicious!

Comment: Yes used it. I believe they mention on their website that they are a part of Callcredit. based in Yorkshire. You can check their info on their website and companies house to clarify your doubts.

Comment: That's a shame. They can't find my details apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formulas used by the three major credit bureaus (Experian, TransUnion, Equifax) are proprietary trade secrets. They're each slightly different, and are fed differing data, so your "score" is likely to deviate from bureau to bureau.

A Google search for "Credit Score Estimator" returns several pages of links to FICO estimation web apps. Be careful; you're feeding personal information about your credit history into these sites in many cases. I just ran through [this one](http://www.creditsourceonline.com/credit-score-simulator.html), which does not ask for any identifying information, and estimated my score to within 40 points, and is accurate as of the last time I checked my actual scores.